# Error with trait bound on gfx_core::Resources

Tags: rust

I have a problem with this code:

```
extern crate piston_window;
extern crate find_folder;
extern crate gfx_graphics;
extern crate gfx;
extern crate gfx_device_gl;

use piston_window::*;
use gfx_device_gl::{Resources, Output, CommandBuffer};
use gfx_graphics::GfxGraphics;

struct Object {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    sprite: Option<Texture<Resources>>,
}

impl Object {
    fn new() -> Object {
        Object {
            x: 0.0,
            y: 0.0,
            sprite: None,
        }
    }
    fn mov(&mut self, x: f64, y: f64) {
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
    }
    fn render(&self,
              g: &mut GfxGraphics<Resources, CommandBuffer<Resources>, Output>,
              view: math::Matrix2d) {
        let square = rectangle::square(0.0, 0.0, 100.0);
        let red = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];
        match self.sprite {
            None => {
                rectangle(red,
                          square,
                          view.trans(self.x, self.y).trans(-50.0, -50.0),
                          g);
            }
            Some(ref sprite) => {
                image(sprite, view.trans(self.x, self.y).trans(-50.0, -50.0), g);
            }
        }
    }
    fn setSprite(&mut self, sprite: Texture<Resources>) {
        self.sprite = Some(sprite);
    }
}

struct Game {
    position: f64,
    one: bool,
    two: bool,
    three: bool,
    four: bool,
    five: bool,
    six: bool,
    seven: bool,
    eight: bool,
    nine: bool,
    player: Object,
}
impl Game {
    fn new() -> Game {
        Game {
            rotation: 0.0,
            player: Object::new(),
            one: false,
            two: false,
            three: false,
            four: false,
            five: false,
            six: false,
            seven: false,
            eight: false,
            nine: false,
        }
    }
    fn on_load(&mut self, w: &PistonWindow) {
        let assets = find_folder::Search::ParentsThenKids(3, 3) //Cerca la cartella assets
        .for_folder("assets").unwrap();
        let tris = assets.join("x.png");
        let tris = Texture::from_path(&mut *w.factory, &tris, Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new())
            .unwrap();
        self.player.setSprite(tris);
    }
    fn on_update(&mut self, upd: UpdateArgs) {
        self.position += 3.0 * upd.dt;
        if self.one {
            self.player.mov(100.0, 100.0);
        }
        if self.two {
            self.player.mov(100.0, 200.0);
        }
        if self.three {
            self.player.mov(100.0, 300.0);
        }
        if self.four {
            self.player.mov(200.0, 100.0);
        }
        if self.five {
            self.player.mov(300.0, 100.0);
        }
        if self.six {
            self.player.mov(200.0, 200.0);
        }
        if self.seven {
            self.player.mov(200.0, 300.0);
        }
        if self.eight {
            self.player.mov(300.0, 200.0);
        }
        if self.nine {
            self.player.mov(300.0, 300.0);
        }
    }

    fn on_draw(&mut self, ren: RenderArgs, e: PistonWindow) {
        e.draw_2d(|c, g| {
            clear([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], g);
            let center = c.transf((ren.width / 2) as f64, (ren.eight / 2) as f64);
            self.player.render(g, center);
        });
    }

    fn on_input(&mut self, inp: Input) {
        match inp {
            Input::Press(but) => {
                match but {
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D1) => {
                        self.one = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D2) => {
                        self.two = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D3) => {
                        self.three = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D4) => {
                        self.four = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D5) => {
                        self.five = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D6) => {
                        self.six = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D7) => {
                        self.seven = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D8) => {
                        self.eight = true;
                    }
                    Button::Keyboard(Key::D9) => {
                        self.nine = true;
                    }
                    _ => {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let title = "Tris"; //Titolo della finestra
    let mut window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new(title, [800, 600]) //Crea la finestra
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .build()
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| { panic!("Failed to build PistonWindow: {}", e) });

    let mut game = Game::new();
    game.on_load(&window);

    let assets = find_folder::Search::ParentsThenKids(3, 3) //Cerca la cartella assets
        .for_folder("assets").unwrap();
    let tris = assets.join("tris.png");
    let tris = Texture::from_path(&mut window.factory,
                                  &tris,
                                  Flip::None,
                                  &TextureSettings::new())
        .unwrap();

    let x = assets.join("x.png");
    let x = Texture::from_path(&mut window.factory, &x, Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new())
        .unwrap();

    let o = assets.join("o.png");
    let o = Texture::from_path(&mut window.factory, &o, Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new())
        .unwrap();


    while let Some(e) = window.next() {
        // Inizia il ciclo e disegna la roba sotto
        window.draw_2d(&e, |c, g| {
            clear([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], g);
            image(&tris, c.transform, g);
        });

        match e.event {
            Some(Event::Update(upd)) => {
                game.on_update(upd);
            }
            Some(Event::Render(ren)) => {
                game.on_draw(ren, e);
            }
            Some(Event::Input(inp)) => {
                game.on_input(inp);
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=aaf7bae8313c7116a1ffd5eb6c6a3a05&version=stable&backtrace=0)

When I try to compile it, it says the error:

> ```
> the trait bound `gfx_device_gl::Resources: gfx_core::Resources` is not
> satisfied [E0277]
>      src/main.rs:14 sprite: Option<Texture<Resources>>,
> ```

And the second error:

> ```
> error: the trait bound `gfx_device_gl::Resources: gfx_core::Resources`
> is not satisfied [E0277]
>     src/main.rs:39     fn setSprite(&mut self, sprite: Texture<Resources>) {
>     src/main.rs:40         self.sprite = Some(sprite);
>     src/main.rs:41     }
> ```

How should I fix it? I looked online but found nothing about it.

Comment: It is generally best to present a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). There seems to be a lot of code in the excerpt you present that does not contribute to the error, by removing it you would (1) learn yourself better where the error is located and (2) make it more obvious to would-be answerers. Finally, once sufficiently reduced, it would be a prime candidate for including directly within the question: links are a supplement, they should NEVER be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for helping me fix my post. The problem is clearly in these two lines, at 14 and 39, I have no idea if it is a wrong type, if Piston changed with updates and now the syntax is different or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an identical compile error on very similar code and setting

```
gfx_device_gl = "=0.9.0"
```

in Cargo.toml caused it to stop happening for me. Previously, I was using `0.11.0`.

After changing this, I get other (I believe separate/independent) compilation errors, but perhaps this solves your predicament.